# Why the nextButton/startButton does not work?

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am working on a project on Khan Academy in which I have to create a game with at least 3 levels. I have developed most of the game but when I tried to proceed from one level to next the game somehow stops.

Here is the full project:
[Project Link](http://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-project-hoppy-beaver-extreme/6062040944541696)

```
/**
 * Contains 3 levels
 * 
 * 
 * Changed Ground
 * Brown rectangle is replaced with Dirt Block.
 * 
 * Scoring system changed
 * Collecting Good sticks gets 1 point.
 * Collecting Bad sticks gets -1 point. (i.e. loses point).
 * Hitting rocks will lose 1 point.
 * 
 **/
var level = 0;
var nosOfSticks = 5;
var target = 0;
var speed = 1;
var endLevel = false;
var buttonClicked = false;
var levelButtonEnabled = false;
var startButtonEnabled = true;

var Beaver = function(x, y) { // Beaver Constructor
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Happy");
    this.sticks = 0;
};

Beaver.prototype.draw = function() { // Draw function to draw beaver
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width-40);
    this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height-50);
    image(this.img, this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
};

Beaver.prototype.hop = function() { // Hop function to make beaver hop
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Jumping");
    this.y -= speed * 5;
};

Beaver.prototype.hopLeft = function() {
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Jumping");
    this.x -= speed * 5;
};

Beaver.prototype.hopRight = function() {
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Jumping");
    this.x += speed * 5;
};

Beaver.prototype.fall = function() { // fall function makes beaver fall on the ground
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Happy");
    this.y += speed * 5;
};

Beaver.prototype.checkForStickGrab = function(stick) { // function that checks sticks grab
    if ((stick.x >= this.x && stick.x <= (this.x + 40)) &&
        (stick.y >= this.y && stick.y <= (this.y + 40))) {
        stick.y = -400;
        this.sticks++;
    }
};

Beaver.prototype.checkForBadStickGrab = function(badstick) { // function that checks badsticks grab
    if ((badstick.x >= this.x && badstick.x <= (this.x + 40)) &&
        (badstick.y >= this.y && badstick.y <= (this.y + 40))) {
        badstick.y = -400;
        this.sticks--;
    }
};

Beaver.prototype.checkForRockHit = function(rock) { // function that checks rocks hit
    if ((rock.x >= this.x - 40 && rock.x <= (this.x + 40)) &&
        (rock.y >= this.y - 30 && rock.y <= (this.y + 40))) {
        rock.x = -400;
        this.sticks--;
    }
};

// Drawing Sticks

var Stick = function(x, y) {  // Stick constructor
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Stick.prototype.draw = function() { // Draw function to draw sticks
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 40);

};

var Badstick = function(x, y) { // Bad Sticks constructor
    Stick.call(this, x, y);
};

//Badstick.prototype = Object.create(Stick);

Badstick.prototype.draw = function() { //Draw function to draw badsticks
    fill(255, 0, 13);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 40);
};

// Drawings Rocks

var Rock = function(x, y) { // rocks constructor
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = getImage("cute/Rock");
};

Rock.prototype.draw = function(x, y) { // function to draw rocks
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    image(this.img, this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
};

var beaver = new Beaver(200, 300);

var sticks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nosOfSticks; i++) {  
    sticks.push(new Stick(i * 100 + 400, random(20, 260)));
}

var badSticks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nosOfSticks/2; i++) {  
    badSticks.push(new Badstick(i * 200 + 400, random(20, 270)));
}

var rocks = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < nosOfSticks * 0.375; i++) {
    rocks.push(new Rock(random(0, 375), i * random() - (i * 100)));
}

var grassXs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) { 
    grassXs.push(i*20);
}

var blockXs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 25;  i++) {
    blockXs.push(i*20);
}

var Button = function (x, y, w, h, color, text, size, font, textcolor, best) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
    this.text = text;
    this.size = size;
    this.font = font;
    this.textcolor = textcolor;
    this.best = best;
};

Button.prototype.draw = function() {
    rectMode(CORNER);
    fill(this.color);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    fill(this.textcolor);
    stroke(this.textcolor);
    textFont(this.font, this.size);
    text(this.text, this.x + (this.w/2 - this.w/2.5), this.y + (this.h/2 + this.size/2.5));
    /*textFont(this.font, this.size / 2);
    text("Best : " + this.best, this.x + 10, this.y + 90);*/
};

Button.prototype.clicked = function() {
    if(mouseIsPressed && mouseX >= this.x && mouseX <= this.x + this.w && mouseY >= this.y && mouseY <= this.y + this.h ) {
        return true;
    }    
};

var nextButton = new Button(315, 360, 75, 30, color(0, 255, 0), "Next Level", 12, "Aerial Bold", color(0, 0, 0));

var startButton = new Button(315, 360, 75, 30, color(0, 255, 0), "Start Again", 12, "Aerial Bold", color(0, 0, 0));

var playButton = new Button(140, 250, 120, 50, color(0, 0, 0), "PLAY", 40, "Aerial Bold", color(255, 255, 255));

var level1Button = new Button(30, 120, 100, 100, color(0, 0, 0), "Level 1", 25, "Aerial Bold", color(255, 255, 255));

var level2Button = new Button(140, 120, 100, 100, color(0, 0, 0), "Level 2", 25, "Aerial Bold", color(255, 255, 255));

var level3Button = new Button(250, 120, 100, 100, color(0, 0, 0), "Level 3", 25, "Aerial Bold", color(255, 255, 255));

var drawWin = function() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    textSize(36);
    text("YOU WIN!!!!", 100, 200);
    nextButton.draw();
};

var drawLoss = function() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    textSize(36);
    text("YOU LOSE!!!!", 100, 200);
    startButton.draw();
};

var movement = function() {
    if (keyIsPressed) {
        if(keyCode === UP) {
            beaver.hop();
        } /*else if(keyCode === LEFT) {
            beaver.hopLeft();
        } else if(keyCode === RIGHT) {
            beaver.hopRight();
        } */
    } else {    beaver.fall();}
};

var drawScore = function() {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    textSize(18);
    text("Score: " + beaver.sticks, 10, 390);
};

var isWin = function() {
    if(beaver.sticks >= target) {
        drawWin();
        speed = 1;
        return true;
    }
};

var isLoss = function() {
    if (beaver.sticks < target ) {
        speed = 1;
        drawLoss();
        return true;
    }
};

var drawBackground = function() {
    //static
    speed = 1;
    background(227, 254, 255);
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    rectMode(CORNER);
    rect(0, height*0.90, width, height*0.10);
    for (var i = 0; i < grassXs.length; i++) {
        image(getImage("cute/GrassBlock"), grassXs[i], height*0.85, 35, 20);
        image(getImage("cute/DirtBlock"), grassXs[i], height*0.85, 35, 60);
        grassXs[i] -= speed;
        if (grassXs[i] <= - 20) {
                grassXs[i] = width;
        }
    }
};

var drawSticks = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sticks.length; i++) {
        sticks[i].draw();
        beaver.checkForStickGrab(sticks[i]);
        sticks[i].x -= speed;
    }
};

var drawBadSticks = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < badSticks.length; i++) {
        badSticks[i].draw();
        beaver.checkForBadStickGrab(badSticks[i]);
        badSticks[i].x -= speed;
    }
};

var drawRocks = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < rocks.length; i++) {
        rocks[i].draw();
        beaver.checkForRockHit(rocks[i]);
        rocks[i].y += speed;
    }
};

var drawLevel = function() {
    speed = 1;
    drawBackground();
    if (level === 1) {
        target = 1;
        drawSticks();
    }
    if (level === 2) {
        target = 1;
        drawSticks();
        drawBadSticks();
    }
    if (level === 3) {
        target = 1;
        drawBadSticks();
        drawSticks();
        drawRocks();
    }
    beaver.draw();
    movement();
    drawScore();
    if (sticks[nosOfSticks - 1].x < -5) {
        isWin();
        isLoss();
    }
};

var drawLevels = function() {
    level = "l";
    background(0, 0, 0);
    level1Button.draw();
    level2Button.draw();
    level3Button.draw();
    if (level1Button.clicked() && level === "l") {
        level = 1;
        drawLevel();
    } else if (level2Button.clicked() && level === "l") {
        level = 2;
        drawLevel();
    } else if (level3Button.clicked() && level === "l") {
        level = 3;
        drawLevel();
    }
};

var drawStart = function() {
    level = 0;
    background(0);
    text("Hoppy Beaver", 75, 50);
    text("Extreme", 120, 100);
    playButton.draw();
    if (playButton.clicked() && level === 0) {
        levelButtonEnabled = false;
        drawLevels();
    }
};

//drawStart();

mouseClicked = function() {
    if (nextButton.clicked() || startButton.clicked()) {
        if (beaver.sticks >= 1) {
            if (level === 0) {
                level = 1;
                sticks = [];
                draw();
                isWin = false;
            }
            if (level === 1) {
                level = 2;
                sticks = [];
                draw();
                isWin = false;
            }
            if (level === 2) {
                level = 3;
                sticks = [];
                draw();
                isWin = false;
            }
            if (level === 3) {
                level = 1;
                sticks = [];
                isWin = false;
                draw();

            }
        } else if (beaver.sticks < 1)  {
            if (level === 1) {
                level = 1;
                sticks = [];
                drawLevel();
                isLoss = false;
            }
            if (level === 2) {
                level = 2;
                sticks = [];
                drawLevel();
                isLoss = false;
            }
            if (level === 3) {
                level = 3;
                sticks = [];
                drawLevel();
                isLoss = false;
            }
        }
    }
};

draw = function() {
    speed = 1;
    if (level === 1) {
        drawLevel();
    } else if (level === 2) {
        drawLevel();
    } else if (level === 3) {
        drawLevel();
    } else if (level === "l") {
        drawLevels();
    } else { drawStart(); }
};
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of a link to your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow. The problem with your code is this bit right here in the drawLevel function.

```
if (sticks[nosOfSticks - 1].x < -5) {
    isWin();
    isLoss();
}
```

At the start of your program you initialize the sticks array with some stick objects in line 124. When level 1 ends and the next button is clicked, you set the sticks array to an empty array `sticks=[]` in the mouseClicked function.
However, you never re-add anything into the sticks array. Thus, when that block of code runs, the element at position `nosOfSticks-1` is undefined, leading to your problem.
My suggestion is to make a for loop after `sticks=[]` to refill the sticks array just like in line 124.
Good Luck!

Also, take a look at this guide for debugging help, [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).